# KDE custom menu action on directories with whitespaces in the name

Tags: scripts, customization, dolphin, kde5

I created a script that takes different directories paths to merge the files inside them into one directory. I would exec this scrict by custom Kde-Dolphin action menu, so I created this .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=inode/directory;
Actions=mergeDir
X-KDE-AuthorizeAction=shell_access

[Desktop Action mergeDir]
Name=Merge this directories
Exec=konsole --noclose -e bash -c '/sc/dirs_merge.py -s %F'
Icon=folder-red
```

Unfurtuntely the %F doesn't consider the escape character for white spaces, so there is an issue when I use this action with directory with withe spaces in the name, because it's not possibile to discriminate a whitespace in the dir-name between white space as directories separator:

*e.g: /transit/mergetest/Test white space 2 /transit/mergetest/Test whitespace 1*

Someone knows a solution to this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `%F` placeholder should handle filenames containing spaces just fine - as noted in the freedesktop documentation for [The Exec key](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.0/ar01s06.html)

> %F    A list of files. Use for apps that can open several local files at
> once. **Each file is passed as a separate argument to the executable
> program.**

So provided your python script knows how to properly handle multiple arguments, you shouldn't need to involve a bash shell at all - just pass the `%F` argument list to your python script directly:

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e /sc/dirs_merge.py -s %F
```

If you *do* really need a bash shell, then pass the arguments as positional parameters and remember to quote the expansion of `$@` to prevent word-splitting by the shell:

```
Exec=konsole --noclose -e bash -c '/sc/dirs_merge.py -s "$@"' bash %F
```

(the second `bash` is just to fill the shell's `$0` parameter - you can substitute any string there).

Comment: only one word: wow.

Comment: Exec=konsole --noclose -e /sc/dirs_merge.py -s %F --> This create the problem, no way to identify arguments with space in the "name".
Exec=konsole --noclose -e bash -c '/sc/dirs_merge.py -s "$@"' bash %F --> This is perfetc, in this way each argument is included between two '. Perfect, many many thanks.

Comment: @Amarabottiglia Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)